# How to capture any error with Webclient?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, webclient

Im trying to capture connection problem when using WebClient. Example, unreachable, timeout etc. Code belows doesnt work, as if there is nothing wrong.

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
try
{
    wc.UploadFileAsync(new Uri(@"ftp://tabletijam/FileServer/upload.bin"), Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\crypto.bin");
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Well... should there be something wrong with the provided code snippet?

Comment: There is nothing wrong in the code. That what i did, but still i cannot know if the upload is commence or not. What im trying to achieve is, how do i know if the client host unreachable, or if there is something wrong with the transmission?

Answer (score 0):

The code you are using, just sends the file ... you need to implement the **Async** part.

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.UploadFileAsync(address, fileName);
webClient.UploadProgressChanged += WebClientUploadProgressChanged;
webClient.UploadFileCompleted += WebClientUploadCompleted;

...

void WebClientUploadProgressChanged(object sender, UploadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Download {0}% complete. ", e.ProgressPercentage);
}
void WebClientUploadCompleted(object sender, UploadFileCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // The upload is finished, clean up
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{
    // trying to make any operation on a file
}
catch (IOException error)
{
    if(error is FileNotFoundException)
    {
        // Handle this error
    }
}
```

use this code but with your scenario